# Constantly out of gas on testprc

Tags: remix, testrpc, out-of-gas

I am trying to connect remix to testrpc, but anything at all I run there gives me an "out of gas" message.

I started the testrpc using

```
testrpc -l 4500000000000
```

So I would have thought it would be OK, the contract itself is nothing right now - just a test contract with a setter and a getter function for a byte32 field.

The usual answer to this seems to be to increase the gas using the -l parameter, but whatever I set doesn't seem to be enough.

Edit: The same error doesn't occur when running on the Javascript VM, only when I connect to testrpc.

There are no arrays or anything like that. The function is just a placeholder for now while I work out how the integration side works.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Functest {
    bytes32 foo; 

    function setFoo(bytes32 _foo) public {
        foo = _foo;
    }

    function getFoo() constant public returns (bytes32) {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the same error happen without connecting to testrpc (e.g. use the JavaVM environment)?

Comment: What is your code trying to do? Some errores will cause out of gas, even if you have enough gas, ie accessing an array out of bounds.

Comment: Only on connection to testrpc. I've pasted the code into the question, but it's really only a dummy function.

Comment: I have the same problem and I tried this command but it didnt work:
testrpc -l 3000000 I even rebooted my computer many many times and checked all forums. i am seriously stuck with this issue of gas limit.
it doesnt show me any problem when i run it on JVM. only when I use web3 provider and connect it with testrpc.

Comment: Do you use truffle? And if yes which version? I run into the same problem with truffle 4.0.1. You could use truffle develop (which is a new feature of truffle 4.0.x) instead of testrpc.

Comment: I haven't tried truffle yet, but interesting that it happens there too.

Comment: Still haven't managed to solve this yet, if anybody has any suggestions?

Comment: @urbanespaceman I've tried your setup and it worked correctly. Make sure there's no another instance of geth/parity running, connect to `http://remix.ethereum.org` (ensure you are not connecting to the https site because browsers security will not allow connections to `http://localhost:8545`), connect with Run/Environment/Web3 Provider and `http://localhost:8545`. There's the possibility another process is using port 8545 on your PC, you can configure testrpc to run in another port `testrpc -p 23458`  and modify the connection to `http://localhost:23458`.